# Visual Studio Community 2015 with Crystal Reports 14

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

I have upgraded my VS to new version VS community 15 which requires CR 14 to work with it. I installed but it is not showing its components in toolbox. Does VS 15 give proper compatibility with CR 14? If So what are the steps to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

Install the [Crystal report service Pack 15](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/SAP+Crystal+Reports%2C+developer+version+for+Microsoft+Visual+Studio+-+Service+Pack+15+-+Fixed+Issues) and check the list of fixed issues: Incident 508399

It works for me with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (with .NET 4.6)

Comment: I want to add chocolatey link here https://chocolatey.org/packages/crystalreports-for-visualstudio

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 is not compatible with crystal reports yet.

Compatibility is planned for the next service pack which is due out sometime in September.

Comment: Also try changing the project properties from Framework 4 client profile to net framework 4

Comment: When SAP says "Developer Version for Visual Studio .NET does NOT support Express Editions of any version of Visual Studio .NET. VS." do they include community editions ?

Comment: I will answer my own comment because I found the information in detail of Kicasd link Incident 508399
VS 2015 Community not detected
2181302 seems resolved in Pack 15. After installing pack 15 I can see the Crystal Reports template in Add New Item window