# How to setup Crystal Report in windows 10 with visual studio 2015

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have `Windows-10 pro 32bit` and `Visual Studio 2015`.

I can't setup crystal report in my windows. I try Version 13_0_13 and 13_0_15 and 13_0_6 but not working and see this error :

```
you must already have visual studio 2010 or visual studio 2012
installed to proceed with this installation
```

What is the issue and how to install proper version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same [question](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3765252) ask in Crystal Reports - Form. While asking there is no support for VS2015, but now it is available and also you can resolved your issue with this [link](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3809485).

Also VS2015 is launch with new .net framework (4.6), which is latest release and Crystal report will now support.

If above will not work check this also:- [Visual Studio Community 2015 with Crystal Reports 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847398/visual-studio-community-2015-with-crystal-reports-14)