# Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

Hi I have a simple question, but I can't find any info about it.

I know that Crystal Reports didn't run with VS Express edition but what is with VS 2015 Community version ? it's working or not ? Someone test it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are right, VS Express is not support Crystal report, but VS2015 community addition support CR. Check this links.

http://www.tektutorialshub.com/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2015/

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

[Visual Studio Community 2015 with Crystal Reports 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847398/visual-studio-community-2015-with-crystal-reports-14)

https://scn.sap.com/thread/3765252

[Crystal reports for Visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430412/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

According to information from [SAP](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

To integrate `SAP Crystal Reports - developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio`, you must run installer executable.

Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into `VS.MSI` files by definition are for runtime distribution only.

By default Windows 10 does not install the 3.5 framework, CR for VS still needs it. Select it by "Turn Windows feature on or off" and choose both options.